# Return query results to main thread without blocking

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, return, coroutine

I'm having trouble with Kotlin coroutines, I'm trying to query a database and return the results to the main thread, but I can't figure out how to do so without "freezing" my main thread. In this case runBlocking would be the culprit, but I'm unsure what to substitute it for. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

```
fun getResults() : List<String> {
    val results = ArrayList<String>()

    runBlocking {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            openConnection()

            try {
                statement = connection!!.createStatement()
                resultSet = statement!!.executeQuery("blah blah blah")
                while (resultSet != null && resultSet!!.next()) {
                    results.add(resultSet!!.getString(1))
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("getList Catch", e.toString())
            }

            closeConnection()
        }.join()
    }

    return results
}
```

Comment: "I'm trying to query a database and return the results to the main thread" -- that's not possible, even with coroutines, unless you expose a `suspend` function from your `ViewModel`. And even then, it can't be a blocking call (e.g., `runBlocking()`), as you block the main thread. I generally steer people towards having their `ViewModel` expose `LiveData`, perhaps populating that `LiveData` via coroutines. See https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-coroutines-rxresult for an example.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm surprised to hear its not feasible, yet again I don't know much about Kotlin. But given this is an Android project, would it be possible to do with Java?

Comment: "I'm surprised to hear its not feasible, yet again I don't know much about Kotlin" -- it has nothing to do with the language. It has everything to do with threads. "would it be possible to do with Java?" -- no. You want a blocking call that does not block. That simply does not exist in either Java or Kotlin (or C/C++ for that matter).

Comment: The Kotlin documentation implies runBlocking's only intended purpose is for the top level main function, which isn't used in an Android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `runBlocking` is unneeded when scoping the blocking task appropriately in tandem with a suspendable coroutine or a callback.

You have a couple options as mentioned:

Suspendable coroutine

```
suspend fun getResults() : List<String> = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->

    openConnection()

    val results = ArrayList<String>()

    try {
        statement = connection!!.createStatement()
        resultSet = statement!!.executeQuery("blah blah blah")
        while (resultSet != null && resultSet!!.next()) {
            results.add(resultSet!!.getString(1))
        }
        closeConnection()
        cont.resumeWith(Result.success(results))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("getList Catch", e.toString())
        closeConnection()
        cont.resumeWith(Result.failure(e))
    }
}
```

anonymous callback

```
fun getResults(cb: (List<String>) -> Unit) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        openConnection()

        val results = ArrayList<String>()

        try {
            statement = connection!!.createStatement()
            resultSet = statement!!.executeQuery("blah blah blah")
            while (resultSet != null && resultSet!!.next()) {
                results.add(resultSet!!.getString(1))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("getList Catch", e.toString())
        }
        cb.invoke(results)
        closeConnection()
    }
}
```

My personal preference is the 2nd option as it removes the need for the consumer of the method to have to be aware and implement suspendable.

```
launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   val results = getResults()
   // handle results
}
```

vs.

```
getResults {
   // handle results
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether this works as intended. If I check the thread name in the getResults callback lambda I'm seeing the same thread as in the getResults implementation.